# Can you help me ID these two helicopters?

Tags: helicopter, aircraft-identification

[image: photo of 2 helicopters in flight]

Hey folks! Desperate to find what these two helicopters are. Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Where and when did you see them?

Comment: Let’s say SE Asia. Sorry, can’t be more specific.

Comment: I’m thinking the one on the left is a PZL W13 Sokol and no idea about the one on right.

Comment: Oh and it was within the last week.

Comment: @AB You mean the one onf the _left_ is a PZL W13 Sokol, I assume?

Comment: There aren't many helicopters with six-bladed rotors. The [Sikorsky MH-53](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_MH-53) is one, though they've been out of service for a while; other variants are still in use.

Comment: I said the left in my original post, but I said W13 by mistake, I meant W-3. :)

Comment: Good catch David about the six blades. Tks. Because of the pointer nose, doesn’t look like a Pave Low to me. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AB Yeah, it's not a Pave Low: it's missing the refuelling boom on the nose and the thingummyjigs (technical term) on the lower fuselage. And Pave Lows haven't flown in 11 years.

Comment: Fairly certain the one on the right is an Enstrom, they usually have a distinctive 3 blade rotor system.

Comment: Thanks Ron, looking it up after you say that, it does have a very similar shape. 

Can anyone confirm/deny my thoughts that the one on the left is a Sokol W-3?  I know the country where they were seen flying is supposed to have them in their arsenal..

Comment: That would be the first W-3 with retractable landing gear.

Comment: That's ultimately where I was leaning, especially since the country in question has purchased them in the past. Thanks Peter.

Comment: The right one is much easier for me to identify, and I am quite sure it is an AS-355 (the two-turbine version of the AS-350).

Answer (score 5):

My guess is an [AW139](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AgustaWestland_AW139) on the left and the [AS355](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurocopter_AS355_%C3%89cureuil_2) on the right. Both are very widely produced models.

Comment: I think the left one has six main rotor blades, whereas the AW139 (and 149, for that matter) have five? If it’s just five, though, the AW149 might also be a contender, with Thai Army apparently being a prime user.

Comment: Thanks fooot and Cpt Reynolds.  The shape/sihouette seem to fit with a AW139/149 but I'm unaware of the country (not Thailand) having purchased any though they're notoriously secretive, so it could be. But I'm trying to see now if they have a capacity to mount weaponry

Comment: I fully agree with the AS-355 on the right, but am less sure about the left one.

Comment: I agree about the left one. Not many options with 6 blades, and it doesn't look to be in military colors. It could be just 5 blades and the AW139 seemed to be the best match.

Comment: I do now wonder whether it’s a Mi-24 or derivative.